# What is the asymptotic order of ${2n \choose 0}\sqrt{n}+ {2n \choose 1}\sqrt{n-1} +...+{2n \choose n}\sqrt{0}$?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

Binomial expansion gives ${2n \choose 0}\cdot2+ {2n \choose 1}\cdot 2 +...+{2n \choose n-1}\cdot2+{2n \choose n}=2^{2n}$. My question is to find the asymptotic order of $$F(n):={2n \choose 0}\sqrt{n}+ {2n \choose 1}\sqrt{n-1} +...+{2n \choose n}\sqrt{0}$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$. In particular, is it true that for all $n$, $F(n)\le C\cdot 2^{2n}$ for some constant $C$?

Comment: Thanks Barry. I was sloppy on my binomial expansion formula, and it has been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In particular, is it true that for all $n$, $F(n)\le C\cdot 2^{2n}$ for some constant $C$?

No.

Let's parameterise the sum slightly non-intuitively (it's in the reverse order to the way you've written it): $$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{2n}{n-i} \sqrt i$$

Then by Stirling's approximation the $i$th term is approximately $$\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}} \frac{(2n)^{2n+1/2}}{(n-i)^{n-i+1/2}(n+i)^{n+i+1/2}} \sqrt i$$ and when $i = o(n)$ that in turn approximates to $$\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt\pi} \sqrt\frac{i}{n}$$

Since there are $\sqrt{n}$ values of $i$ in the range $[\frac12\sqrt n, \frac32\sqrt n)$ you should not expect an upper bound which is asymptotically better than $$2^{2n} n^{1/4}$$

This may not be tight, but it's enough to answer the direct question.

Comment: The $n^{1/4}$ should be in the denominator?

Comment: @sku, no, the argument is that there are (at least) $n^{1/2}$ terms which are $\Omega(2^{2n} n^{-1/4})$, and adding them gives a sum which is $\Omega(2^{2n} n^{1/4})$.

Comment: Also Cauchy-Schwartz gives $O(2^{2n}n^{3/ 4})$:
\begin{align}
F(n) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k}\sqrt{n-k}\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{2n}{k}^2 \right)^{1/ 2}\left(\sum_{j=0}^n (n-j)\right)^{1/ 2}\\
&= \left(\frac12 \binom{2n}{n}^2 + \frac12\binom{4n}{2n} \right)^{1/ 2}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^{1/ 2}\\
&\sim \frac{1}{2} \left( \left(\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\right)^2 + \frac{2^{2(2n)}}{\sqrt{\pi (2n)}} \right)^{1/ 2} n\\
&\sim \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} 2^{2n} n^{3/ 4}
\end{align}

Comment: @adfriedman, I understand the argument from the penultimate line to the last one to be that the second term inside the sqrt dominates, but then the constant seems incorrect by a factor of $(2\pi)^{1/4}$. That aside, I think you should post an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: On further reflection, I understand why you posted it as a comment: it's an upper bound, but the answer to the question consists of a lower bound. So we have $\Omega(2^{2n} n^{1/4})$ and $O(2^{2n} n^{3/4})$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a first-term asymptotic analysis that gets the same result as Peter Taylor above, but with an explicit constant.  Numerically, about 3 digits agreement are obtained for n ~ 1000.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{n-k}\sqrt{k} \sim \binom{2n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\exp{(-k^2/n)}\sqrt{k}=\binom{2n}{n}n^{3/2}\,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\exp{(-n\big(\frac{k}{n}\big)^2)}\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}.$$

In the 1st step the well-known expansion for the central binomial coefficients have been used and the 2nd I'm setting up for the interpretation of the sum as a Riemann integral as n $\to \infty$, i.e.,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{n-k}\sqrt{k} \sim \binom{2n}{n}n^{3/2}\,
\int_0^1\exp{(-n\,x^2)}\sqrt{x}\,dx .$$
The standard asymptotic trick of increasing the upper integral limit go to $\infty$ allows us to explicitly calculate the integral with the gamma function.  Using the Stirling approximation for the binomial and collecting results the answer so obtained is

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{n-k}\sqrt{k} \sim  \frac{\Gamma(3/4)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}
 n^{1/4}2^{2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

Having fun playing with small numbers, I computed the values of

$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{2n}{n-i} \sqrt i$$ for $100 \leq n \leq 10000$ (step size $= 100$). For $n=1000$, the value is almost $1.375\times 10^{6021}$ (!!).

Performing a linear regression
$$\log(S_n)=a+ b n + c \log(n)$$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -1.08076 & 0.00069   & \{-1.08213,-1.07939\} \\
 b & +1.38629 & \approx 0 &  \{+1.38629,+1.38629\} \\
 c & +0.25239 & 0.00010 & \{+0.25219,+0.25259\} \\
\end{array}$$ while using skbmoore's answer, the coefficients would be $ \{-1.06223,1.38629,0.25000\}$.